# remove extra whitespace from json file

Tags: python, json

How do I remove extra space for keys in a json file?
My file looks like this...

```
{
      " bankName " : " State bank of China " ,
" branchDetails " : [
       {
...
```

Expected results:

```
{
      "bankName" : " State bank of China " ,
"branchDetails" : [
       {
...
```

Can I use "strip" method of string to json file (preferably values as well with keys)?

Comment: I don't think there is a magic method to perform this task. Maybe the quickest way is to loads() your json content to obtain plain Python object, then loop on the dict keys to call strip() on them, then dumps() back the result to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your JSON file into a Python data structure, strip all strings, and write it out again:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def json_strip(obj):
    return obj

@json_strip.register(str)
def _(obj):
    return obj.strip()

@json_strip.register(list)
def _(obj):
    return [json_strip(v) for v in obj]

@json_strip.register(dict)
def _(obj):
    return {json_strip(k): json_strip(v) for k, v in obj.items()}

with open(inputfile, 'r') as inf:
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as outf:
        json.dump(json_strip(json.load(inf)), outf)
```

This uses the [`@functools.singledispatch()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to create a series of recursive functions to handle the different types; this requires Python 3.4 or newer.

You may want to adjust the `json.dump()` output using the [`separators`, `indent` and `sort_keys` options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).

Quick demo:

```
>>> json_strip({" bankName " : " State bank of China "})
{'bankName': 'State bank of China'}
```